# WSO2 EI new xml tag using Enrich mediator and when xml tag takes dynamically

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ei, wso2-esb

Is it possible to add new xml tag to xml payload using enrich mediator.

my sample payload -

```
<courses>
   <id>181</id>
   <formatted_name>Learning</formatted_name>
   <score>0</score>
   <status>in_progress</status>
   <issued_certificate />
   <from_timestamp>1626083705</from_timestamp>
   <to_timestamp />
</courses>
```

New tag would be

```
<link> www.google.com </link>
```

I cannot use inline as the source since link is taken dynamically.
So I'm adding new tag to a payload and then property.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <link xmlns="">$1</link>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('login_link')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property description="Get login link payload" expression="//root/*" name="login_link_xml" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
// get original payload back
<enrich description="Restore original payload">
    <source clone="false" property="course_payload" type="property"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
// assign property as a new node inside the courses
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" property="login_link_xml" type="property"/>
    <target action="child" type ="custom" xpath="//courses"/>
</enrich>
```

This gives the same payload after enrich

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a bit different way. Create your 'tag' as **property** type OM, using xpath expresion and function: *concat*, with coded char

```
<property name="my_link" value="devintegra.com" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="linkNode" 
          type="OM" 
          expression="concat('&lt;link&gt;',get-property('my_link'),'&lt;/link&gt;')" 
          scope="default" />
```

And with that property you can **enrich** your body:

```
<enrich>
  <source type="property" clone="true" property="linkNode"/>
  <target action="child" xpath="//courses"/>
</enrich>
```

That should work as you expect.